# Problem using latexdiff and pdflatex with custom command

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, latexdiff

Using latexdiff I have the problem, that by adding new `\section`, I get the following error by trying to run pdflatex.

```
! Argument of \UL@word has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.69 \subsection{\DIFadd{Some Text}}
```

Here you can see the redefined `\section` command...

```
\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@startsection{section}%
{1}     % Structure level
{0mm}   % Indention
{2ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}            % Pre-Margin
{0.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}      % Post-Margin
{\chapterheadfont\Large\bfseries}   % Style
}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
\@startsection{subsection}%
{2}     % Structure level
{0mm}   % Indention
{1.5ex plus 1ex minus 0.5ex}        % Pre-Margin
{0.3ex plus 0.3ex minus 0.3ex}      % Post-Margin
{\chapterheadfont\large\bfseries}   % Style
}
```

How can I fix the problem? It would work for me also to ignore the changed section names.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

(OPs answer, moved from the question.)

I thought it would be more complex, but I found a solution. Using `--exclude-textcmd` allows the ignoring of tags. It works now.

```
--exclude-textcmd="section,subsection"
```

Comment: Where exactly did you put this text?

Comment: What does now mean? Version 1.1.1?

Comment: @sphere: it is put as command line argument to latexdiff.

Comment: would it also work with `git latexdiff`?

Comment: What does it actually mean in layman's terms? Sure I can read the doc, but a hint would be appreciated. What do you mean by "ignoring"?

Comment: @Veridian this should be added as an option of latexdiff command

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thanks so much.

For people wondering, this is what is meant:

latexdiff --exclude-textcmd="section,subsection" draft.tex revised.tex > diff.tex

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had a custom defined command `\r` to make `\autoref` easier to use (`\renewcommand{\r}[2][]{\textbf{\autoref{#2}{#1}}}`). This was causing all kinds of problems for `latexdiff`, and I found I had to use `--exclude-safecmd="r"` to stop latexdiff from enclosing references with its `DIF` commands . `--exclude-textcmd="r"` didn't seem to do anything for me.

Answer (score 6):

It's difficult without an MWE, but I would assume that the difficulty is with `hyperref`, which tries to include underlined/crossed out text as hyperlink given that it is part of a chapter.

The solution is to use `texorpdfstring`, which tells hyperref to use plain text for the hyperlinks. I can't remember the exact commands that `latexdiff` definds, but try something like that:

```
% Redefine these commands for chapter/sections and change below
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hsout}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\sout{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hwave}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\uwave{#1}}{#1}}

%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem}% DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1}%DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\textcolor{blue}{\hwave{#1}}}}% DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\textcolor{red}{\hsout{#1}}}}% DIF PREAMBLE
...
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem with

```
\section{\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{Conclusion}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{Conclusions}\DIFaddend }
```

and [Jörg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87537/23481) did not work for me. What worked was a manual substitution:

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{Conclusion}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{Conclusions}\DIFaddend }{Conclusions}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on a very large document, and based on Jörg suggestion, I just removed the call to hyperref package (and \hypersetup ) in the difference tex file and it compiled fine. Just a fast workaround.

Comment: Disagree.  This answer worked better than the others for me.

Comment: If `autoref` is used from `hyperref` package, then commenting out `hyperref` will disable `autoref`. So, commenting out `hyperref` is not the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this:
`\subsection{\DIFadd{Experimental results added}}`,
then it got error with MiKTeX.

I change it to this:

```
\section*{\DIFadd{Experimental results added}}
```

or `\subsection*{\DIFadd{Experimental results added}}`,
then it's ok but no section numbers.

So I change it again:

```
\section[]{\DIFadd{Experimental results added}}
```

or `\subsection[]{\DIFadd{Experimental results added}}`.

Hope this could solve your problem (not perfect: section number color is still black).

Comment: I added some comments on how to Joeg's solution but they were deleted by Peer Review. Anyway, there seems to have been some misunderstanding on how to use Joeg's solution. So, I am writing on this again. The key to use his solution is to comment out the following two default commands generated by latexdiff: \providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE;
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by treating `hyperref` differently while building the diff. There's an [issue](https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff/issues/13) on the latexdiff repo that talks about it:

`latexdiff old.tex new.tex --packages=hyperref > testdiff.tex`

After this `pdflatex` on the diff started working for me.